# structural directive not working with two-way binding

Tags: angular

I am newbie to Angular 8 and getting stuck with trying to use *ng-if and 2 way binding.
It did not run as expected:

template file:

```
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="true" [(ngModel)]="socialClass" >Rich
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="false" [(ngModel)]="socialClass" >Poor
    </label>    

    <ng-container *ngIf="socialClass; else elseBlock"><h3>Rich </h3></ng-container>
    <ng-template #elseBlock>
        <h3>Poor</h3>
    </ng-template>
```

component.ts file:

```
... class StructuralDirectiveComponent implements OnInit {
public socialClass:boolean;
}
```

I am not sure while when I click the radio button, it did not show up the corresponding value in ng-template

Answer (score 0):

You need to import FormsModule in the related module.

And then if it's Angular 2+ you should use `[ngModel]="socialClass" (ngModelChange)="socialClass = $event"` instead of `[(ngModel)]="socialClass"`.

and values should be wrapped like that `[value]="false"` and `[value]="true"`

Comment: Try to wrap the values too

Comment: I've added this info in the answer `[value]="false"`

Comment: thanks very much! the reason why it did not work at the beginning is because I did not wrap the values attributes in []... Do you why attribute value of boolean must be wrapped in [] to make it work while strings do not?

Comment: all attributes in html are strings and `value="false"` means `"false"` as a string. Angular adds a layer of abstraction that allows to keep an original type but for that attributes should be added as angular bindings.

Comment: thanks a lot for this useful info... can you please give me some references to Angular doc where it mentions this explicitly? or any articles writing about this...

Comment: The doc is here: https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControlDirective#description

Comment: And this is some info about value and ngValue https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dyif1Xy9GY8, but now you can consider `[value]` in the same way as `ngValue`.

Answer (score 0):

The `socialClass` variable is possibly of type string when assigned from the input.

#### Option 1

Try to set the type of `socialClass` to `any` and compare it to string literal `'true'` in the `*ngIf`.

Controller

```js
public socialClass: any;
```

Template

```html
<div>
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="true" [(ngModel)]="socialClass" >Rich
  </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="false" [(ngModel)]="socialClass" >Poor
  </label>
</div>

<ng-container *ngIf="socialClass === 'true'; else elseBlock"><h3>Rich </h3></ng-container>
<ng-template #elseBlock>
    <h3>Poor</h3>
</ng-template>
```

#### Option 2

Or, if you wish to use booleans to denote the value, you could introduce an additional variable (eg. `choice`) in the controller.

Controller

```js
public socialClass: boolean;
public choice = true;
```

Template

```html
<div>
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="optradio" [value]="choice" [(ngModel)]="socialClass" >Rich
  </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="optradio" [value]="!choice" [(ngModel)]="socialClass" >Poor
  </label>
</div>

<ng-container *ngIf="socialClass; else elseBlock"><h3>Rich </h3></ng-container>
<ng-template #elseBlock>
    <h3>Poor</h3>
</ng-template>
```